# How to check if a string in an NSMutableArray isEqualToString X?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

Sorry if this is basic, but I can't get my head around this. I have an array and would like to go through every single object in it and see if it isEqualToString:@"something". If tried this, but it will crash:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ([myNSMutableArray count]); i++) {

    NSLog(@"i = %i", i);

    if ([[myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"something"]) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }


}
```

I'll get:

```
    2011-07-14 13:38:40.983 MNs[21416:207] i = 0
2011-07-14 13:38:40.985 MNs[21416:207] -[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c976f0
2011-07-14 13:38:40.987 MNs[21416:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c976f0'
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot. This is how I created the array:

```
NSMutableArray *myNSMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
        [myNSMutableArray addObject:@""];
        [myNSMutableArray addObject:@"something"];
        [myNSMutableArray addObject:@""];
    }
```

EDIT2:

So sorry, the problem was that I tried to copy a mutable array ... so all of your answers are correct, I just need to pick one now, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This,

```
for (int i = 0; i < ([myNSMutableArray count]); i++) {

    NSLog(@"i = %i", i);

NSString *stringToCheck = (NSString *)[myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([stringToCheck isEqualToString:@"something"]) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }


}
```

Comment: Ok :-). Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: If you use `stringValue` after `objetcAtIndex` instead cast to `(NSString*)` and create a new string variable is better and more professional!

Answer (score 2):

From the error message you get, the problem seems lying with how you fill up your `myNSMutableArray`. In fact,

```
 [myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]
```

returns `__NSArrayM` instead of `NSString`, hence the error you get.

Could you explain what kind of objects do you add to the `NSArray`?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question and added what objects I add. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if ([[[myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] stringValue] 
                                         isEqualToString:@"something"])
```

because elements in array are of `ID` type. You need to cast to `NSString`!

And ensure that `myNSMutableArray` is created correctly and isn't in autorelease!

`Alloc` + `init` make array in manual release, instead `[NSMutableArray array]` is in autorelease.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have strings there, you should try casting it before trying to compare:

```
if ([(NSString*)[myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"something"]) {
```

Comment: sorry, but i still get the same error message. i updated my question if that helps. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

NSMutableArray *myNSMutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",nil];

```
for (int i = 0; i < ([myNSMutableArray count]); i++) {


    if ([[myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello 1");
    } else
    {
    }


}
```